# How can I group item by their values

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
<ul>
        <li v-for="item in birth" :key="item.id">
          <div v-for="infos in item.infos" :key="infos.pic">
            <div class="day">Birthday : {{infos.date}}</div>
            <img class="photo" :src="infos.pic">
            <div class="name">{{infos.name}}</div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

I need to display some infos, and I want to group them by their birthdays. For the moment, they are displayed liked this :

Birthdays : 06/28
Pic
Steve

Birthdays : 06/28
Pic
John

Birthdays : 06/30
Pic
Chris

And I want them to be displayed like this

Birthdays: 06/28
Pic
Steve,
Pic
John

Birthdays: 06/30
Pic
Chris

Is it possible to make this directly with v-for and some v-if ?

Comment: you're gonna need to do a transform on the data in the birth property.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this `groupBy` in lodash:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#groupBy

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it directly with vue. What I would do is rearrange the data as it fits you server side or use a computed client side.